# isdigit() to include checking spaces

Tags: c

I'm doing some IO and one of the lines is, `number number`, however when I use,

```
if(isdigit(buffer) > 0) { ... }
```

It fails, I believe it's because there is a space between each number. Is there a way to not include the space when using isdigit()? Or is there an alternative to this? Thanks.

Comment: `isdigit()` operates on characters, not strings...

Comment: isDigit expects a character as input, and i guess buffer is just a character array or, more specifically, a pointer to a string/character array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `isdigit()` and friends work on characters, not strings. Something like this will do what you want:

```
bool is_digit_or_space(char * buffer) {
    while ( *buffer ) {
        if ( !isdigit(*buffer) && !isspace(*buffer) ) {
            return false;
        }
        ++buffer;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Full code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_digit_or_space(char * buffer) {
    while ( *buffer ) {
        if ( !isdigit(*buffer) && !isspace(*buffer) ) {
            return false;
        }
        ++buffer;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    char good[] = "123 231 983 1234";
    char bad[] = "123 231 abc 1234";

    if ( is_digit_or_space(good) ) {
        printf("%s is OK\n", good);
    } else {
        printf("%s is not OK\n", good);
    }

    if ( is_digit_or_space(bad) ) {
        printf("%s is OK\n", bad);
    } else {
        printf("%s is not OK\n", bad);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./isdig
123 231 983 1234 is OK
123 231 abc 1234 is not OK
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```